# Why Laravel tests created with make:test extends from a different TestCase when the --unit flag is used

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-artisan

With Laravel, you can use Artisan to make a test class, using `php artisan make:test` command.
Optionally, the `--unit` flag can be used to create a unit test instead of a feature test.

I recently had to write an unit test which required some setup before being executed.
Unfortunately, I encountered an error when I tried to use a facade: `A facade root has not been set`.

After some digging, I saw that a test class generated with the `--unit` flag extends from `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` wherehas a feature test extends from `Tests\TestCase`. And that's why i wasn't able to use a facade, the application doesn't boot when using a test class generated with `--unit`.

Does somebody knows why it is designed like this ?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

`php artisan make:test`

This command generates a *Feature* test.  A Feature test is typically used to test integrations of collaborating classes.

`php artisan make:test --unit`

This commands generates a *Unit* test.  A Unit test is typically testing units of code, such as classes, or methods in classes.  A Unit test will substitute any dependencies with Mocks or other Test Doubles so that class/function is tested in isolation.

---

Generally, you would probably want to "mock" the facade in your unit tests. Here is relevant information from the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mocking#introduction):

> When testing Laravel applications, you may wish to "mock" certain aspects of your application so they are not actually executed during a given test. For example, when testing a controller that dispatches an event, you may wish to mock the event listeners so they are not actually executed during the test. This allows you to only test the controller's HTTP response without worrying about the execution of the event listeners, since the event listeners can be tested in their own test case.

Additionally, [here is documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mocking#mocking-facades) on mocking the `Cache` facade (as an example):

> We can mock the call to the Cache facade by using the shouldReceive method, which will return an instance of a Mockery mock. Since facades are actually resolved and managed by the Laravel service container, they have much more testability than a typical static class. For example, let's mock our call to the Cache facade's get method:

```php
namespace Tests\Feature;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Tests\TestCase;

class UserControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testGetIndex()
    {
        Cache::shouldReceive('get')
                    ->once()
                    ->with('key')
                    ->andReturn('value');

        $response = $this->get('/users');

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It is interesting but unfortunately it doesn't really answer my question, which is "Why `php artisan make:test --unit` produces a class that extends from `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` and `php artisan make:test` produces a class that extends from `Tests\TestCase` ?

Comment: @toyi: See my updated answer above. Maybe the extra explanation will help?